# Possible to make global settings for all users in TextPad?

Tags: installation, settings, textpad

I have installed Textpad on a Windows server accessed by many users, as it is my editor of choice for numerous reasons.

I have a number of non-standard syntax definitions (R, STATA, SQL), the files for which are stored in the `system` folder of the main Textpad installation.

However, every user has to individually create the `new document class`. Is there a way to define document classes (and indeed other settings, e.g. `show line numbers`) for all users, perhaps during installation? This would be really useful.

Thanks.

Comment: That is going to depend. Which version of TP are you using?

Comment: Also, if you're using TP6 or TP7, the XML config files location will vary if you're using Win XP or Win7.

Comment: While I am very TP savvy, I do encourage use of the TP forum for all things TP. http://forums.textpad.com/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the input Kennah. It is a Windows 2008 server actually, I've installed TP7. Will check you the forums - thanks. If I find the answer I guess I'll post it - if you do please do likewise. Best, Luke

Answer (score 2):

For TP7, the settings are in two XML files--GUIState.xml and ConfigState.xml

For a Win7 Workstation, they are here:

```
%APPDATA%\Helios\TextPad\7
```

Not sure where they'll land on a Windows Server.

If you have Syntax Definition  files (.syn) that you want others to use and have access to, you could store them in an accessible network location.  You can use UNC paths, so you would not have to fret about ensuring everyone maps to the P: Drive or R: Drive or whatever.

If you look in the ConfigState.xml file, scroll down to , and you'll see the location of the Syntax Definition files.  It may look something like:

```
<value name="Syntax" type="string">C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Helios\TextPad\7\Syntax</value>
```

I would configure one Workstation how you want it, using the TP7 GUI.
Configure, Preferences

Set up all the Document Classes you want in the standard configuration, folder locations, etc.

Once you have it like you want it, install TP7 on another Workstation, and replace those default .xml files with the ones from the configured Workstation.

Comment: Nice solution - definitely worked for the user I tried. An ideal solution I guess would be to have a "global" XML setting file that was searched for syntax definitions, rather than having to do this for all users of the server. I'll accept this answer if nothing else is presented (and/or I don't find another solution to post). Many thanks